# Altair python - how to align x axis (=0) for charts within a for

Tags: python, data-analysis, altair

I want to align al charts generated in a loop, but x axis do not start at the same vertical line, because of the 'y' labels.
See below:

[image]

```
for campo in [col for col in nomina.columns if col!= 'Fecha ingreso']:
    a = alt.Chart(nomina[[campo]]).mark_bar().encode(
        x='count(' + campo + '):Q',
        y=alt.Y('' + campo + ':N', sort='-x')
    )
    display(a.resolve_scale(x='shared'))
```

and I would like to see like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

already figured it out. I just had to add charts in a list, then use alt.vconcat(mylistcharts)!

```
charts = []
for campo in [col for col in nomina.columns if col!= 'Fecha ingreso']:
    a = alt.Chart(nomina[[campo]]).mark_bar().encode(
        x='count(' + campo + '):Q',
        y=alt.Y('' + campo + ':N', sort='-x')
    )
    charts.append(a.resolve_scale(x='shared'))
alt.vconcat(*charts)
```